# How can I fix this error in Mokito? Wanted but not invoked

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, mvp

**this is the real function : onMapLoaded()**

```
override fun onMapLoaded(isWorking: Boolean) {
    if (isWorking) {
        activeArea?.let { interactor?.fetchHeatMapTiles(it.id) }
    } else {
        interactor?.fetchReservationCapacities()
    }
    if (activeArea != null) {
        view?.showArea()
    }
    if (view?.hasLocationPermission() == true) {
        locateMe()
    }
}
```

**These is the basic settings for testing**

```
private lateinit var view: MapContract.View
private lateinit var interactor: MapContract.Interactor
private lateinit var presenter: MapPresenter

@Before
override fun setup() {
    super.setup()
    view = mock()
    interactor = mock()
    presenter = MapPresenter(view, interactor)
}
```

and this is my **test** function:

```
@Test
fun `Presenter should show user's current location immediately when map loaded`() {
    val mockedPresenter = mock<MapPresenter>()
    whenever(mockedPresenter.onMapLoaded(false)).thenCallRealMethod()
    whenever(view.hasLocationPermission()).thenReturn(true)
    mockedPresenter.onMapLoaded(false)
    verify(mockedPresenter, Times(1)).locateMe()
}
```

**But I get this error:**

[image]

Please help me fix this bug

**I want to make sure that the locateMe() function is executed
But the test fails and is not run at all**

Comment: instead of posting pictures of your code paste your code in question

Comment: Sure, the photos were deleted and the codes were inserted

Comment: Is ``mapPresenter.getView()`` returning that `view` you're mocking? If it's null, the code block with `locateMe()` won't run